# In array not working?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$values = array('0', 1, 2);
if (in_array($values2, $values, false) || $values2 == 0) {
```

Values2 is the submitted value, and in this case it was 3, 3 isn't in the array, so shouldn't the if condition execute?

Comment: With the code you have typed, the "if" will result in a no, unless you change the condition to have a "not"

Comment: Are you saying the block in the `if` didn’t run and you think it should or it ran and you think it shouldn’t?

Comment: Or is the `== 0` supposed to negate the result? It has a higher precedence than `||`.

Comment: Well I'm trying to display an error which is why I used the if condition, I'm basically checking if the submitted value ($values2) is in the array (using the false), the value 3 is not in the array, so the bracket after display an error. The second part is the OR checking if the value submitted is 0. Basically display error if the value is 0, or if the value is not in the array. @minitech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if the value is *not* in the array, use the aptly named not operator:

```
if (!in_array($values2, $values, false) || $values2 == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the if statement should not be entered.

`in_array` will return false, since the element wasn't in the array.